# docusign custom connector pricing plans and API base path doubts

Tags: docusignapi

I have some doubts regarding the custom connector we are trying to build for docusign : -

1. Regarding the license plan that need to be bought by the customers who will be granting access for our connector to collect data from their docusign organization account. I am looking at the link https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing. API access support is mentioned in only the advanced solution. So I was wondering whether only we need to have "Advanced solutions plan with APIs support" plan or all our customers need to API access support in order to fetch their data.
2. As per the documentation, to make the REST API calls we need two fields 'base_uri' and 'account_id' (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints). Now, the response of userInfo API call gives an array of accounts and its respective fields. My doubt is, if multiple authenticated users (more than one accounts) are returned in this array but all are part of same organization, will they all have different account_ids. Main concern here is, will there be several Base Paths (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints#form-your-base-path) to make API calls?

   2a. Further question is, what is the significance of 'is_default' field?
   Is this related to main account (if is_default is true) using which we will create our Base Path?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a tech/engineering forum I'm going to answer only question #2 as question #1 is more of a business/sales question.

The reason you may get multiple accounts is that an authenticated user in DocuSign can be a member of multiple accounts. That said, it's the same user. Meaning, say foobar@blah.com has an account 123 with company X and account 456 with his school, then it's possible that when foobar@blah.com authenticates (With the same password!) to DocuSign we have a list of accounts associated with that user. We give you all of them when you make the API call. The default one is the main one that you would see when you log into our web app. You can decide yourself as the user which one is the default. Users who log into our web-app then see an option at the top-right to change accounts. 
and yes, every API call is associated with a specific account. So when you construct the urls for your API - you do need to know which account for this user you are making the API call for. Your application can decide how to handle this.
Hope this helps.